# Android resource linking failed Android Studio 3.3.1

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am trying to generate APK from my source code and getting below errors.

```
F:\breeze-2019-3-14\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:88: error: unexpected element <action> found in <manifest><application><activity>.
F:\breeze-2019-3-14\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:90: error: unexpected element <category> found in <manifest><application><activity>.
```

My Manifest file is like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.zaravoipcall.breeze">

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.zaravoipcall.breeze.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <permission android:name="com.ipsmarx.dialer.MsgDBProvider"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.zaravoipcall.breeze.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.sip.voip"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


    <application
        android:name="com.ipsmarx.dialer.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="com.ipsmarx.newdesign.LoginActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_display_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.ipsmarx.newdesign.OutgoingCall"
            android:enabled="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name="com.ipsmarx.newdesign.Splashscreen"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_display_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ipsmarx.newdesign.ModeSelectDialog"
            android:allowTaskReparenting="false"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.ipsmarx.dialer.ConnectedCall"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
            <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.headset.action.VENDOR_SPECIFIC_HEADSET_EVENT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VOICE_COMMAND" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_BUTTON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ipsmarx.newdesign.Tabbar"
            android:label="@string/login"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ipsmarx.contactslist.ui.ContactDetailActivity"
            android:label="Contact Details"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.ipsmarx.contactslist.ui.ComposeActivity"
            android:label="Compose Invite"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <receiver android:name="com.ipsmarx.dialer.Receiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.ipsmarx.dialer.WakeLockManager"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.ipsmarx.dialer.custom.intent.action.cpuwakelock" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.ipsmarx.dialer.NotificationController"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.ipsmarx.dialer.custom.intent.action.REG_STATUS" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.ipsmarx.dialer.custom.intent.action.MISSED_CALL" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.ipsmarx.dialer.custom.intent.action.SHOW_CALLLOG" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.ipsmarx.dialer.custom.intent.action.SHOW_CHATTHREAD" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.ipsmarx.dialer.custom.intent.action.MSG_STATUS" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.ipsmarx.dialer.SipService"
            android:enabled="true" />
        <service android:name="com.ipsmarx.dialer.ContactSyncService" />

        <!--<provider-->
            <!--android:name="com.ipsmarx.dialer.MsgDBProvider"-->
            <!--android:authorities="@string/app_name"-->
            <!--android:exported="false"-->
            <!--android:permission="android.permission.CONFIGURE_SIP" />-->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.ipsmarx.pushnotification.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.ipsmarx.dialer" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.ipsmarx.pushnotification.GCMIntentService" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.ipsmarx.newdesign.SignUp"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sign_up"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.ipsmarx.newdesign.SignUpByPhone"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sign_up_by_phone"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.ipsmarx.newdesign.ForgotPassword"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_forgot_password"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.ipsmarx.video.RTCActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="fullUser"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="6b5afe577fa0e4476d354af38bcdc075eee398a6" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
            tools:replace="android:configChanges" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.purchase.InAppPurchaseActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.IAPTheme" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I am using Android Studio 3.3.1 and Gradle 4.10.1
I am trying to figure it from last two hours and not getting idea whats wrong in my code. Let me know if someone can help me for solve the issue. Thanks

Comment: post your manifest file.

Comment: @VishrutMavani Sorry, I have added it now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `Manifest.xml` is corrupt, this:

```
 <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

should be (`android.intent.action.MAIN` is optional):

```
 <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
     <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
 </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this portion to

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.ipsmarx.newdesign.LoginActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_display_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
       <intent-filter> 
     <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```